# Return in json from stored procedure in MVC web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
public class VersionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<AutoCompleteCompany> acCompany(string term)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<AutoCompleteCompany> co= new List<AutoCompleteCompany>();

        try
        {
            ds = getdetails(term);//privae method returns dataset
            co = ds.Tables[0].ToList<AutoCompleteCompany>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }

        return co;
    }
}
```

Properties below

```
public class AutoCompleteCompany
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Converts dataset to list

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
    List<T> result = new List<T>();

    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
        result.Add(item);
    }

    return result;
}

private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
{
    T item = new T();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(System.DayOfWeek))
        {
            DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), row[property.Name].ToString());
            property.SetValue(item, day, null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (row[property.Name] == DBNull.Value)
                property.SetValue(item, null, null);
            else
                property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

Webapiconfig

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>
> MessageDetail: no action was found on the controller 'AutoComplete' that matches the request.

and below custom method works

```
public string GetAccess(string id)
{
    return "value3";
}
```

Please suggest a way to return dataset from stored procedure in to json as result (web api rest)

Comment: which url endpoint you are trying to use when you received the error `MessageDetail: no action was found on the controller 'AutoComplete' that matches the request.`?

Comment: http://ocalhost:5555/api/Version/acCompany/somevalue.............this got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call something like :

```
http://yourhostname/Api/Version/acCompany?term=someString
```

Your `Controller` name is `Version` not `AutoComplete`!

Answer (score 1):

Because your controller name is Version, not AutoComplete. You just use wrong url.

Answer (score 1):

Change your return type to IActionResult, and wrap your list in an OkObjectResult, like so...

```
return Ok(co);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a List you can just return a JsonResult like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult acCompany(string term)
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  List<AutoCompleteCompany> co= new List<AutoCompleteCompany>();
  try
  {
    ds = getdetails(term);//privae method returns dataset
    co= ds.Tables[0].ToList<AutoCompleteCompany>();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  { 
  }
  return Json(new { co {);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered via query string. But as mentioned by OP in comments, if you want to invoke your endpoint like this: `http://localhost:5555/api/Version/acCompany/somevalue`

then you will need to modify your webapi action parameter to taken in `id` instead of `term` as shown below:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<AutoCompleteCompany> acCompany(string id)
{
   // rest of your action code would make use of id instead of term
}
```

After this change, you should be able to invoke it as http://localhost:5555/api/Version/acCompany/somevalue. When this is invoked, id will take in somevalue.

The reason why you need to use id is because the way how they are configured in webapiconfig.cs.